# ANDROID there is no R.java

Tags: java, android

Something weird...  I was under the impression that R.java is created automatically by the Android platform (ADT).

My question is as follows:

When I start Eclipse Mobile Juno 32 bit for Windows and go to the project I was working the day before, I find that I have an empty gen folder (there is no R.java, etc).

What should I do to prevent this from happening?  It is really annoying...

Thanks.

Comment: Check console for problems. Your project has not built properly

Answer (score 2):

There are many posts on stackoverflow, which give suggestions regarding this. However what I can say with my experience is that, whenever R.java is not formed, their might be a error in some file. If not, then I just clean the open project and let it recompile. Cleaning the project works most of the time for me.

Answer (score 0):

ADT won't generate this file if there is an error in your resources/layouts.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to clean the project by clicking project > clean. This will clean your project.

Make sure you select the "Build Automatically" option just below the "clean" menu as well. This way, each time you clean your project it will build the project automatically for you.

If the build hit an error, please post it.

Please also make sure you are using the appropriate Java compiler and the Android version by checking on the project properties.